# Displaying date on the x axis with Highcharts using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have the following C# code:

```
public JsonResult Graph()
{
    var result = new Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> { { DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime(), 1000 }, { DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime(), 2000 }, { DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2).ToUniversalTime(), 5000 } };

    return Json(result.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I look in firebug the JSON data looks like:

```
[{"Key":"\/Date(1319515200000)\/","Value":1000},{"Key":"\/Date(1319428800000)\/","Value":2000},{"Key":"\/Date(1319342400000)\/","Value":5000}]
```

My Highcharts configurations looks like:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: []
}

jQuery.getJSON("/graph", null, function (items) {
    var series = {
        type: 'column',
        data: []
    };

    jQuery.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
        series.data.push({
            name: item.Key,
            y: item.Value
        })
    });

    options.series.push(series);

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    chart.render();
});
```

The x-axis will not display my dates. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal>()
```

I basically passed the date as a string to the view and ended up using

```
Date.parse(item.Key)
```

on the client side. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, `item.Key` contains something like "Date(1319342400000)", can you try the following:

```
jQuery.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
    var dateStr = item.Key;
    var dateVal = dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf('(')+1, dateStr.indexOf(')'));
    series.data.push([dateVal, item.Value]);
});
```

Also, you do not need the following line:

```
chart.render();
```

And if the above does not work, can you check the value of `item.Key` as follows:

```
jQuery.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
    alert(item.Key);
    series.data.push(//...
```

**Update:**

Then you do not need to use `substring` and `indexOf`. Just change you `jQuery.each` as follows:

```
jQuery.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {        
    series.data.push([item.Key, item.Value]);
});
```

Comment: @Thomas: Did you try `alert(item.Key);` to see the content of `item.Key`?

Comment: Yes, it contains 1319342400000 but it doesn't show up on the x axis.

Comment: I don't think its enough to plug in the 1319342400000 number into the key spot. I think you'll have to do something like series.data.push([new Date(item.Key), item.Value]);